# Display issue when reading a file in php

Tags: php, file

i have an simple xls file and it's print me that :

PK!b�h^�[Content_Types].xml �(����N�0E�H�C�-Jܲ@5��*Q>�ēƪc[�ii����B�j7���{2��h�nm���ƻR����U^7/���%��rZY�@1__�f��q��R4D�AJ�h>����V�ƹ�Z�9����NV�8ʩ����ji){^��-I�"{�v^�P!XS)bR�r��K�s(�3�`c�0��������7M4�����ZƐk+�|\|z�(���P��6h_-[�@�!���Pk���2n�}�?�L��� ��%���d����dN"m,�ǞDO97*�~��ɸ8�O�c|n���E������B��!$}�����;{���[����2���PK!�U0#�L_rels/.rels �(���MO�0��H�����ݐBKwAH�!T~�I����$ݿ'T�G�~����<���!��4��;#�w����qu*&r�Fq���v�����GJy(v��*����K��#F��D��.W ��=��Z�MY�b���BS�����7��ϛז�� ?�9L�ҙ�sbgٮ|�l!��USh9i�b�r:"y_dl��D���|-N��R"4�2�G�%��Z�4�˝y�7 ë��ɂ�����PK!��3_I�xl/workbook.xml�Umo�8�~���w�M0oj� o�J{����~�tr�+�9c�T���CH�����^���c?3����ӡm�&.���ϐi��%������ LcP�+i#:�6�`~�����^�ݝ;�am�J��mE�Z:���u`��l������^2Z5c�ml!�n)��!���U���blY�f����P�~X���=p-���� ��q��'P�h�����5��� ���#��&0�������@�3�7�cdc�*��1x�kK��uO���AV� �{���0Hk�J�� 9qs��y�v3Kנ}�mu��h蠲�+V�M�b�^mȱ�Gހ�qV1��IΗ�(YE�F]��x��� �m���b�������jns�I-@���{�Aa���Wiѻᒪ�e�6�����߂��MٰS��}�K����2i�c�8�����d���RI�/�ϐ�?���^�����Eq� ��J�6��4O��x؊]B�e> �7�BzQ!��c�5��t�L���b�(y�|

my code is : i tried :

```
 $file = file_get_contents('...\TestExcel.xlsx');
    echo $file;
```

and also :

```
$file = file('......\TestExcel.xlsx')
   foreach($file as $files){
echo $files;
}
```

Whats wrong please ?

Comment: A .xlsx file is actually a zip archive.

Comment: what do you mean ? in property it is a excel file.

Comment: Excel files are zip archives internally. Each sheet is a file in the archive.

Comment: http://www.fileformatcommons.com/xlsx-file-format/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a binary file. An XLSX file is a Microsoft Excel Open XML Format Spreadsheet file. It's a ZIP-compressed, XML-based spreadsheet, which you can't open the way you tried.

I think it is possible to unzip it and get to the actual content of the spreadsheet, which is basically just xml.